# Python dictionary: tuple as a key and a list of tuple as a value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary structure in Python that contains `only one` key-value pair.
The key is a tuple and the value is a list of tuples.
example: `{(element1, element2): [(element1.1, element2.1), (element1.2, element2.2).....]}`

I am trying to iterate through this dictionary in order to get the key and then the value. Then I want to construct another dictionary that will contain:

```
{ element1: element2
element1.1: element2.1
element1.2: element2.2 }
```

What I have tried is the following:

```
field_dictionary is the dictionary that I previously described.

for (k,v), l in field_dictionary:
    log_dictionary[k] = v
    for (element1, element2) in l:
       log_dictionary[element1] = element2
```

What I get is an error:

```
for (k,v), l in field_dictionary:
ValueError: too many values to unpack, expected 2
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I wonder where you get such "dictionary"? also can you post FULL dictionary so we can understand how to help you

Comment: @JiříBaum I added it

Comment: not a [mre] - add your example source dictionary, add what the result should be, add what your result is and where your problem lies.

Comment: @ilyasJumadurdyew Can't a dictionary have a tuple as a key and a list of tuples as a value?

Comment: No, at least it should not. That's why it's calling KEY not keys typple, the princip is that you have one variable name and its value

Comment: That code looks good; what's the problem?

Comment: Do you mean `for (k,v), l in field_dictionary.items():` ? (Note the `.items()`)

Comment: There's no problem having a tuple as the key; it's fairly common

Comment: @JiříBaum, so when one of the developers will write such a dictionary you will say "good job, that code looks good, no problem"? As mentors we should not only response to the question but also show the correct way in order to prevent future misunderstanding of the programming approach. And this approach is completely wrong.

Comment: Ah, of course - missing `.items()`

Comment: Sure, it can be an entirely good data structure depending on the context - which we don't have here

Comment: @JiříBaum So the dictionary that I have described, is wrong (even if it works)? Do you think I should change the structure and remove the tuple?

Comment: I disagree! If it's good data structure then why the author wants to make it normal? The answer is "because it can not be used as json dictionary". That's the problem, it fits json structure control, but it useless. The only correct context here "Some one gave me such a dictionary and i HAVE TO DEAL with it".

Comment: @user1234, Sure! Just look on tonns of json dictionaries, none of them have key as a tuple. It can be heavy and have many keys in it, but still it will be handy.

Comment: @user1234 your dict is valid and if someone is so confident that python is wrong for providing tuples as valid dict keys: they should write a pep.

Comment: Using a tuple as a dictionary key is perfectly valid and frequently very useful; it only seems odd because the elements are named `element1` and `element2` rather than having meaningful names

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain
spam = {('element1', 'element2'): [('element1.1', 'element2.1'), ('element1.2', 'element2.2')]}
key, value = list(spam.items())[0]
eggs = dict(chain((key,), value))
print(eggs)
```

output:

```
{'element1': 'element2', 'element1.1': 'element2.1', 'element1.2': 'element2.2'}
```

or if you prefer

```
for key, value in spam.items():
    eggs = dict(chain((key, ), value))
print(eggs)
```

same output